# How to set listener for two diferent events on recyclerView?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener, onitemclicklistener

I am trying to implement two different listeners for the cardview on my recyclerview adapter. I think I have to use the element id in order to handle the event, but I do not know quite how to do it. This is my adapter view holder in which I call one of the listeners and which works just fine.

```
class ProductListViewHolder(itemView: View, listener: OnItemClickListener ) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    var lytProductInfo: LinearLayout? = null
    var btnAddProduct: Button? = null

    init {
        
        lytProductInfo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.lytProductInfo)
        btnAddProduct = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnAddProduct)

        lytProductInfo!!.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            if (itemView.hasFocus()) {
                itemView.clearFocus()
                //hide keyboard when item has been clicked
                if (itemView is EditText) {
                    val imm = itemView.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(itemView.getWindowToken(), 0)
                }
            }
            val position = adapterPosition
            if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                //click function
                listener.onClick(position)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

and this is how I call it from the class

```
productListAdapter!!.setOnItemClickListener( object: ProductListAdapter.OnItemClickListener {
            override fun onClick(position: Int) {
                val saleId = productList[position].idProduct
            }

        override fun onItemClick(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
            val saleId = productList[position].idProduct
        }
    })
```

The second listener would come from the btnAddProduct.

How can I do this?

Comment: do you want to detect the click on adapter from your base class?

Comment: thanks for the reply. Yes, since I have more control over the events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

implement this on your adapter class

```
interface OnItemClickListener : AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
        fun onInformationClicked(position: Int, v: View?)
        fun onAddClicked(position: Int, v: View?)
    }
```

Then on your viewholder

```
lytProductInfo!!.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener { v ->
                val position = adapterPosition
                if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                    listener.onInformationClicked(position, v)
                }
            })

        btnAddProduct!!.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener { v ->
            val position = adapterPosition
            if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                listener.onAddClicked(position, v)
            }
        })
```

Then on your parent class

```
productListAdapter!!.setOnItemClickListener( object: ProductListAdapter.OnItemClickListener {
            
        override fun onInformationClicked(position: Int, v: View?) {
            showProductInfo()
        }

        override fun onAddClicked(position: Int, v: View?) {
            addProduct()
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a callback from adapter like this,

create a parameter in your constructor,

```
class YourAdapter(val onYourCallback:(Int)-> Unit):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
    
    
    }
```

invoke it in adapter like this,

```
onYourCallback(position)
```

You can receive the callback in your activity like this,

```
YourAdapter(){position->
 callYourFunctionHere()
}
```